# git server refusing password or ssh-key

Tags: git, ssh, git-remote

I currently have a git server I user at home set up for multi-user private repos like below

```
/opt/git
/opt/git/me/..all my projects here
/opt/git/someotheruser/...all his/her projects here
```

I have the git-shell in-place and now after a few months am trying to get access to my repo from a different box its not letting me do so I still am able to push and all that from my laptop but just can't get to use my new desktop to connect to the server. What do i need to do am using ubuntu and the latest git version.

Comment: What sort of errors are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new machine has a different SSH key. You need to upload the SSH public key from this new machine to git-shell so that git-shell can recognize you. (You can have as many SSH public keys as you need there.)